# Creating generic list from classproperties

Tags: c#, .net

am trying to make class which keeps data about student, and his courses list with marks. But when i tried to add data for testing i got error at "student.courses.Add(course);", that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Could anyone give me  a hint  what am doing wrong?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var student = new Student();
    student.id = 1;
    student.name = "John";
    student.lastName = "K.";

    var course = new Course();
    course.code = 123;
    course.nameOfCourse = "Course Name";
    student.courses.Add(course);
}
```

```
public class Student
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public List<Course> courses { get; set; }
}


public class Course
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string nameOfCourse { get; set; }
    public int mark{ get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to initalize `student.courses`.  `student.courses = new List<Course>();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not initializing `courses` property:

```
    var student = new Student();
    student.Courses = new List<Course>();
    student.Id = 1;
    student.Name = "John";
    student.LastName = "K.";
```

But it is better to initialize it inside `Student` class, so it would be:

```
public class Student
{
    private List<Course> courses = new List<Course>();

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses 
    { 
       get
       {
          return courses;
       }
       set
       {
          courses = value;
       }
    }
}
```

Side note: it is better to name public properties with Upper case and private fields with lower case.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to *call* method Add on *null value* (which is student.courses).
Try re-designing your code into something like that:

```
public class Student
{
    // Courses are always exist, but list may be empty
    private List<Course> m_Courses = new List<Course>();

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    // There's IMHO no need in set accessor 
    // (lack of "set" is a good thing to prevent "student.courses = null;" code)
    public List<Course> courses { 
      get {
        return m_Courses;
      } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Courses `list` in `Student` is never initialized. The easiest way to fix this with your code is to write class `Student` is like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public List<Course> courses { get; set; }

    Public Student()
    {
        courses = new List<Course>();
    }
}
```

Like this, you can forget about having to initialize courses after making an instance of `Student`. Otherwise, you would have to do it manually with every instance you create, like this:

```
var student = new Student();
student.courses = new List<Course>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initialize your `student` but since you didn't initialize `courses` property, it is `null` as a default because it is a *reference type*. (`List<Course>`)

```
student.courses = new List<Course>();
```